# Is it possible to detect several parts/joints of human body using Project Tango?

Tags: google-project-tango

Is there anyway to detect human body parts and joints like shoulder, wrist, neck, thigh joints, etc using project tango.

Comment: Im sure you could write your own function to make that happen. So yes there is a way

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with Tango API. But Tango provides enough data to process, and it's possible to leverage some 3rd party library to do this, potentially OpenNI. But again, there's no example or tutorial on how to do that now, you might need to explore those frontier a little bit.